# how to open a pdf file in silverlight from clientbin folder?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I have a product.pdf in my clientbin(silverlight) folder which contains detail about product on click of button just i want to open that pdf i used following code it's working fine locally after hosting it is giving HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. how can i do that one please help me

** service and calling aspx page in silverlight**

```
  Dim uri As New Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "/ClientBin/product.pdf")
        'HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri, "_blank")
        Dim path As String = uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString()
        ' HtmlPage.Window.Eval("window.open('" & path & "')")
        HtmlPage.Window.Eval("document.location.href='" & path & "';")
```

** Error code After hosting **

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: You code example is confusing. You appear to be trying to open the file on your hosting website (which makes no sense). Can you explain in more detail what is on your client and what you want to happen?

Comment: I have a product.pdf in my clientbin(silverlight) folder which contains detail about product on click of button just i want to open that pdf how can i do that one please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are redirecting to the wrong resource.

So I suggest you throw out thte redirect for the moment and replace it with some logging output. 
Just print out the value of `path` and see where it points to.

**CAUTION:** only do this if you're on an internal test system